# umlauts in comments in preambel with knitr cause problems with texi2dvi

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I found some errors with umlauts in comments with knitr in latex. First my mini-example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,        % ß 
               a4paper      % page format
               ]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

  <<code>>=
    rnorm(30)
  @

\end{document}
```

And this errors a shown:

```
Error in texi2dvi(file = file, pdf = TRUE, clean = clean, quiet = quiet,: Running 'texi2dvi' on 'minimalexample.tex' failed. LaTeX errors: ! LaTeX Error: Environment knitrout undefined. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 \definecolor {shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color{fgcolor}\begin{... The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have ! Undefined control sequence. l.6 ...shadecolor}{rgb}{0.969, 0.969, 0.969}\color {fgcolor}\begin{kframe} The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have ! LaTeX Error: Environment kframe undefined. See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation. Type H <return> for immediate help. ... ! LaTeX Error: Environment alltt undefined. See the La Calls: knit2pdf -> <Anonymous> -> texi2dvi In addition: There were 13 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Execution halted

Process exited with error(s)
```

I use Texstudio (V 2.9.4) as my editor and my knitr version is 1.12.3.

Is there a chance to use umlauts in comments and avoid these errors?

Comment: From what can I make out of this [link in german](http://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?73123-scrartcl-cls-not-found) ,  you need `babel ` ,`inputenc`, `selinput`  and `oberdiek` packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I got the solution.

It didn't affected only the comments. Every umlaut caused that Error. The file was encoded in iso-8859-1 and R was running with utf-8. I found it out in R with:

```
Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your solution. You can [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) if you don't expect better answers from other users.